# Open Windows Terminal PREVIEW from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-11, windows-terminal

Is there a way to start a Windows Terminal *Preview* process? I know you can start the regular Windows Terminal using `wt.exe`, however, I am using the preview version and would like to open a terminal preview instance from a program. I have searched Google, but I always just seem to find how to open the regular Windows Terminal.

If I open the executable path from task manager, I get to an exe which I cannot open because I apparently don't have sufficient rights to do - it probably has to do with the fact that I use the version from Windows Store. Do I have to reinstall it from GitHub? I thought that since I can run it from the start menu there should be a way to do so from a program, maybe there is a shortcut which I have the execution rights for?

Comment: Have you looked at using the PowerToys app, which (I believe) comes with the preview terminal included?

Comment: I do have PowerToys installed, but how would that help me execute it from command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They **both** use `wt.exe` as an alias to launch the app. You can manage which one gets started under "Manage App Execution Aliases" in windows Settings by turning one off and the other on:

[image: screenshot]

More details in the answers here: [Path and Name of exe file of windows terminal preview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62894666/7411885)

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way to change that alias, for example to wtp.exe?

Comment: @RcCookie You can manage and create new aliases in the registry under: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` (or same path using `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` for just the current user profile). However, it looks like wt gets installed to a path using its version number, so any updates to the app could recreate the default stuff and/or break custom aliases